# CreateUserWizard control problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i put data in, but no mdf file is created. No database is created.. Why is that?

An extract from the book that i have read now:

> At this point, the CreateUserWizard control uses the ASP.NET Membership class behind the scenes to create a new user. The default membership provider creates the aspnetdb.mdf file (if it doesn’t exist already) and then adds the new user record. Once this process is complete, the CreateUserWizard control shows a message informing you that the user was created. Miraculously, all of this takes place automatically even though you haven’t configured anything in the web.config file and you didn’t create the database file in advance.

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd : you should well format your question before yo hope for any answer on SO.put minimal possible code atleast what you have tried at your end

Comment: there is no code!!! it is a control. The whole point of the use of the control is that you dont use ado.net and code in general. i use visual studio 2010. I added that control, launched the application and no database was created!!

Comment: At this point, the CreateUserWizard control uses the ASP.NET Membership class behind the scenes to create a new user. The default membership provider creates the aspnetdb.mdf file (if it doesn’t exist already) and then adds the new user record. Once this process is complete, the CreateUserWizard control shows a message informing you that the user was created. Miraculously, all of this takes place automatically even though you haven’t configured anything in the web.config file and you didn’t create the database file in advance.

Comment: i added some extract from the book

Comment: See, that's the problem with code miracles and automagic solutions: when they break, there is no useful way to debug them :(

Comment: why did people give me 2 negative points? what did i do?

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1: Refresh your solution. The file might be hidden under App_Data folder. Check in the file system i.e. your physical folder.

2: Check your web.config to make sure if there are any specific configuration related to membership provider or connectionstring.

3: Handle CreateUserError event to see if it gives any more info.

4: Check your Event Log to see if there are any errors.

5: Launch ASP.NET Website Configuration tool and see if the user you created exists there.

Or we need more info like web.config settings and your CUW code(if customized).

Comment: The refresh worked..lol..i cant believe the solution was so simple. Another question. How would that new database interact with my existing database..can i use querries to extract or modify details from both?

Comment: It won't interfere or interact with another database. If you want to link your existing table with membership, you should explicitly create those tables and not use the automatically generated DB. Check this for more info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx